# Unable to create a customer set to a foreign currency on IDS

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are posting the following XML to IDS to create a customer on a foreign currency in Quickbooks Desktop. But, the customer is always getting created on the home currency. The QB company is set to multicurrency, home currency is USD and the foreign currency is CHF (active and has an exchange rate in QBD). What are we doing wrong?

```
<OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId>

<ExternalRealmId>123485035</ExternalRealmId>

<Customer>

    <CustomField xsi:type="StringTypeCustomField" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

        <DefinitionId idDomain="NG">154889</DefinitionId>

        <Value>309</Value>

    </CustomField>

    <TypeOf>Person</TypeOf>

    <Name>CHF Customer</Name>

    <Address>

        <Country>GBR</Country>

        <CountrySubDivisionCode>GBR</CountrySubDivisionCode>

        <Tag>Billing</Tag>

    </Address>

    <Email>

        <Address>chfcust@gmail.com</Address>

        <Tag>Business</Tag>

    </Email>

    <GivenName>CHF</GivenName>

    <FamilyName>Customer</FamilyName>

    <DBAName>CHF Customer</DBAName>

    <OpenBalance>

        <CurrencyCode>CHF</CurrencyCode>

        <Amount>0</Amount>

    </OpenBalance>

</Customer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Intuit Data Services v2 for QuicKBooks for Windows does not support global currency yet. v3 of the Service will fully support multi currency.

V3 is not available to the public yet. We are preparing to announce a v3 roadmap to external developers soon.

regards,
Jarred

Comment: Here is a link to our blog about the upcoming v3 Webinar - http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/01/v3-come-along-for-the-ride.html